# weird shading after boolean

Tags: rendering

[image]

[image]

[image]

what to do, i am new to this, i have to fill to 30 characters but the question is plain that and have submitted the captures

[image]

Comment: Hello please share the object (not the rest of the file)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=9JJsrdj6" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/9JJsrdj6/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Edit* mode you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Clear Sharp*, in the *Data panel > Geometry Data* > click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* in order to reset the shading, then under *Normals > Auto Smooth* choose 10°,  in *Edit* mode select all and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* and in the *Operator Box* (bottom left of your 3D view) choose an *Angle* of 1°, also press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance* and in the *Operator Box* choose a *Distance* of 0.001 to merge the overlapping vertices:

[image]

Comment: man you are a beast, thank you, how did you come with that solution? why is happening? i have seen a lot of persons use the limted disolve, is any answer why everyone uses it so usually? also is there any good course you can recommend me about it?

Comment: You had several problems here like overlapping vertices and ngons (faces with more than 4 vertices, avoid them when faces are not flat and co-planar), this doesn't help to have a good shading, also resetting the shading in order to use the Auto Smooth

Comment: thanks it worked